# Alternative for Sharepoint Designer (custom-workflow)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

In office 2016 there is no SharePoint Designer. The new view in SharePoint Online doesn't support transitioning to SharePoint Designer any more. And even the 2013 Designer doesn't support as much as the 2010 version.

To me it looks like Microsoft is abandoning it's designer functionalities. We use the designer functionalities a lot to make for example workflows.

1. Are there any decent alternatives for the designer functionalities?
2. Are there any decent alternatives for creating/adapting custom workflows?

My employer is in favor of free or low cost solutions (many employees)

I know SharePoint 2013 still works with the current version, but am looking for alternatives that will still work after Microsoft's disabling of the Return to classic SharePoint button. (My libraries tend now to switch almost daily to the new view)

Comment: For now those Modern/New Experiences do not allow any modification, no branding, no adding script. Microsoft is the SAAS provider and you have to accept what they provide. So its not about alternatives... there just is no tool (for Modern Experiences)

Comment: For now it is cool to me to have something that gives me at least the functional functionalities of the Designer. Personalisation would of course be a great bonus.

Comment: Check this [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What're the alternatives?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New way creating workflows using SharePoint online is Microsoft Flow

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/

New way of creating responsive views is PowerApps

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/

Both these tools are integrated with new SharePoint list experiences.

https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/25/modern-sharepoint-lists-are-here-including-integration-with-microsoft-flow-and-powerapps/

[image]

Comment: Note these features are still in Preview mode and it is unclear as to what the licensing and limits will be at this point. Until that is all clarified, there is SharePoint Designer 2013 as Benny mentions.

Answer (score 3):

For SharePoint 2016, you use SharePoint Designer 2013. It works out of the box just the same way you would use it in a SharePoint 2013 farm.

[Download here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491)